# Displaying date in react functional control

Tags: reactjs

What I understand is that react functional components should be pure functions. They should not call any impure functions e.g. Date().
But what actually is the problem with this code?

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ name }) =>  <p>Today is {Date()}</p>
```

Comment: you should have a name for function and return the paragraph:
    export default function Page ({ name }) { return  <p>Today is {new Date()}</p> }

Comment: no need, it is the default export. What I would like to know is what actually is wrong with this component because it calls Date().

Comment: no there is nothing wrong with component.

Comment: but isn't it impure? It calls Date().

Comment: Impure functions are fine. Functions with *side-effects* are less fine, but still manageable in many situations. The Date constructor has no side-effects, so don't worry about using it.

Comment: Primarily, it will not update — you would need to regenerate and rerender it. See e.g. [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element) for more details. Secondarily, it is not as easy to test. As said by others, there are no dangerous reasons in case of `Date`.

Comment: no, you may use many helpers function inside a component they don't make your component impure.

Comment: @whowhenhow "_What I understand is that react functional components should be pure functions_": Can you explain that in more detail, and can you include a link to support for the reason that you think that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purity (in [the definitive sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)) is not a requirement for React functional components. What [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only) actually state is:

> **All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props.**
>
> Of course, application UIs are dynamic and change over time. In the [next section](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), we will introduce a new concept of “state”. State allows React components to change their output over time in response to user actions, network responses, and anything else, without violating this rule.

Your example function uses no props, and it definitely doesn't mutate any props, so (according to the React definition of purity) it's a pure function.

Comment: Cool, I missed that part about props!

Comment: I don't quite see it. The [docs](https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure) says that "React components... must always return the same JSX given the same inputs". Hence, according to that, the example violates React's purity requirements.