# In React, is a function that includes useEffect always NOT pure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm explaining in a course what is a pure function (or pure component in React) and I have the code below which always returns the same result based on the inputs.

My question is: Is this component pure? I think yes because it always returns the same results, but I'm wondering if somehow the sleep in the code makes it not pure?  Thoughts?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function MyComponent({length = 3}) {
  const speakers = [
    {
      id: 10808,
      firstName: "Antony",
      lastName: "Ross",
      imageUrl: "/images/Speaker-10808.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 1725,
      firstName: "Brad",
      lastName: "Irby",
      imageUrl: "/images/Speaker-1725.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 8590,
      firstName: "Chris",
      lastName: "Richardson",
      imageUrl: "/images/Speaker-8590.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 5996,
      firstName: "Craig",
      lastName: "Berntson",
      imageUrl: "/images/Speaker-5996.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 187,
      firstName: "Dave",
      lastName: "Nielsen",
      imageUrl: "/images/Speaker-187.jpg",
    },
  ];
  const [speakerListFiltered, setSpeakerListFiltered] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchSpeakers() {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      setSpeakerListFiltered(speakers.slice(0,length));
    }
    fetchSpeakers();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        {speakerListFiltered.map((speakerRec) => {
          return (
            <div className="col-12" key={speakerRec.id}>
              <img src={speakerRec.imageUrl} width="200" height="200" />
              
              <h4>
                {speakerRec.firstName} {speakerRec.lastName}
              </h4>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you use the definition of ["A React component is considered pure if it renders the same output for the same state and props."](https://blog.logrocket.com/what-are-react-pure-functional-components/#:~:text=A%20React%20component%20is%20considered%20pure%20if%20it%20renders%20the%20same%20output%20for%20the%20same%20state%20and%20props.) then it is pure, if you're going off of the functional programming definition of a pure function ("same output for the same input, no state") then it is not pure

Comment: Either way, does this matter? "functional components cannot leverage the performance improvements and render optimizations that come with React.PureComponent since by definition, they are not classes.", so you're just adding an extra categorization that doesn't have any useful meaning

Comment: The new beta documents are pretty good at explaining it and I think your example meets the spirit of what "pure" intends (in react) https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure#

Comment: The React definition of purity is not the classical definition. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70921916/438273).